# writing a prime factorization program C

Tags: c, algorithm, primes

I am trying to write a program that shows the results of prime factorization as below:

prompt: Input a positive integer

result examples:

100 = 2^2*5^2

It is a composite integer !

13 = 13

It is a prime number !

I tried to write it only with the basic loops, not using sophisticated techniques because it was for beginner's class. The problem is that when I enter 100 as an input, the result is just

100 =

being printed and the program stops there. Other than that, it gives me results I intended. Can anyone help me find what part of this code is the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int inputNumber (int* input); 
int primeFactors (int input);

int main (void) {

int input;

while ( 1 ) {
    inputNumber (&input);
    primeFactors (input);
}
return 0;
}

int inputNumber (int* input){
    printf("\nInput a positive integer : ");
    scanf("%d", input);

    if(*input == 0){
    printf("\n End of program");
    exit(0); 
    }
    return;
}

int primeFactors (int input){
    int cnt = 0, i = 3, cnt_sum;

    printf("%d = ", input);

    if(input > 0){
        while ( input % 2 == 0){
        cnt++;}
        if(cnt == 1){
            printf("%d",2);}
        else if( cnt > 0 && cnt != 1){
            printf("%d^%d",2,cnt);
        }
        cnt_sum += cnt;
        for ( ; i <= sqrt(input); i = i+2){
            cnt = 0;
            while(input % i == 0){
                cnt++;
                input /= i;
            }
            if(cnt == 1){
                printf("%d",i);
            }
            else if( cnt > 0 && cnt != 1){
                printf("%d^%d",i,cnt);
            }
            cnt_sum += cnt;
        }
        if(cnt_sum > 1){
            printf("\nIt is a composite number !\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("%d\nIt is a prime number !\n",input);
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("\nIt is an invalid number !\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: have you debugged your code?

Comment: Does this only happen with 100 as input?

Comment: `while ( input % 2 == 0){cnt++;}` loops infinitely if `input` is even.

Answer (score 1):

There were few bugs.

1. `while ( input % 2 == 0){cnt++;}` loops infinitely if input is even( @Marian )
2. `if(input > 1){` instead of `if(input > 0){`. since 1 is neither prime nor composite.

**Corrected function:**

```
int primeFactors (int input){
    int cnt = 0, i = 3, cnt_sum;

    printf("%d = ", input);

    if(input > 1){
        while ( input % 2 == 0){
            input/=2;
            cnt++;
        }
        if(cnt == 1){
            printf("%d",2);}
        else if( cnt > 0 && cnt != 1){
            printf("%d^%d",2,cnt);
        }
        cnt_sum += cnt;
        for ( ; i <= sqrt(input); i = i+2){
            cnt = 0;
            while(input % i == 0){
                cnt++;
                input /= i;
            }
            if(cnt == 1){
                printf("%d",i);
            }
            else if( cnt > 0 && cnt != 1){
                printf("%d^%d",i,cnt);
            }
            cnt_sum += cnt;
        }
        if(cnt_sum > 1){
            printf("\nIt is a composite number !\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("%d\nIt is a prime number !\n",input);
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("\nIt is an invalid number !\n");
    }
}
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/foLHD4)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing some steps in your algorithm, as well as checking redundant conditions in your `primeFactors` function.

```
int cnt = 0, i = 3, cnt_sum;
```

Because these won't ever be negative, you can change the type to `unsigned`.

```
while ( input % 2 == 0){
    cnt++;
}
```

This `while` statement will loop infinitely if `input` is odd, because nothing is done to change `input`. You can add `input = input / 2;` to stop this.

```
if(cnt == 1){
    printf("%d",2);}
else if( cnt > 0 && cnt != 1){
    printf("%d^%d",2,cnt);
}
```

The `else if` expression can be reduced to an `else` statement, because `unsigned` variables are always greater than 0 and we already know `cnt != 1`, otherwise the first statement would be triggered.

```
while(input % i == 0){
    cnt++;
    input /= i;
}
```

The `while` statement is all good here, how peculiar. :P

```
if(cnt == 1){
    printf("%d",i);
}
else if( cnt > 0 && cnt != 1){
    printf("%d^%d",i,cnt);
}
```

Same deal here as with the if / else if statements before: change the `else if` to `else`.

With these corrections applied (and some style inconsistencies fixed), the function now looks like this:

```
int primeFactors (int input) {
    unsigned cnt = 0, i = 3, cnt_sum;

    printf("%d = ", input);

    if (input > 0) {
        while (input % 2 == 0) {
            cnt++;
            input /= 2;
        }

        if (cnt == 1) {
            printf("%d", 2);
        } else {
            printf("%d^%d", 2, cnt);
        }

        cnt_sum += cnt;

        for ( ; i <= sqrt(input); i += 2){
            cnt = 0;

            while (input % i == 0) {
                cnt++;
                input /= i;
            }

            if (cnt == 1) {
                printf("%d", i);
            } else {
                printf("%d^%d", i, cnt);
            }

            cnt_sum += cnt;
        }

        if (cnt_sum > 1) {
            printf("%d\nIt is a composite number !\n");
        } else {
            printf("%d\nIt is a prime number !\n",input);
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("\nIt is an invalid number !\n");
    }
}
```